# Using Regular Expressions with Shell Scripting

Tags: regex, shell

I have been learning about shell scripting and regular expressions.
I want to find a way to extract a specific part from the file name below.

```
 profiles_060315091024_30398-r-00006.avro
```

I want to extract the number 30398 from the file name.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `awk`:

```
str='profiles_060315091024_30398-r-00006.avro'
awk -F'[_-]' '{print $3}' <<< "$str"
30398
```

`-F'[_-]'` is setting a custom field separator as `_` or `-`

Comment: Would I have to change something if I wanted to store the number "30398" in a variable? Sorry I should've asked that in the initial question.

Comment: You can do: `myvar=$(awk -F'[_-]' '{print $3}' <<< "$str")`

Comment: Thank very much. Is the '{print $3}' necessary?  What is it used for?

Comment: yes `print $3` is required so that `awk` can print 3rd field in the given input.

Comment: Could also be done without invoking `awk` as `IFS='_-' read x x myvar x <<< "${str}"`...

Answer (score 0):

Using shell only. I assume you want the digits between the underscore and the hyphen.

1. regular expression (bash specific)

   ```bsh
   filename=profiles_060315091024_30398-r-00006.avro
   if [[ $filename =~ _([0-9]+)- ]]; then num=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; fi
   echo $num
   # => 30398
   ```
2. using parameter expansion (any POSIX shell)

   ```sh
   tmp=${filename##*_}  # remove from the start up to last underscore
   tmp=${tmp%%-*}       # remove the first hyphen until end of string
   echo $tmp
   # => 30398
   ```